# extracting hex colors form jpeg, store in data.frame, and then plotting with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, jpeg

Like the title says. I have an image that I want to extract the hex values for the color, store in a data.frame and then plot using ggplot.

Here's what I have:

```
library(ggplot2)
aws.logo = 'https://eventil.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/group/avatar/8626/medium_highres_470196509.jpeg'

temp = tempfile()
download.file(aws.logo, temp, mode = 'wb')

## matrix of colors
y = jpeg::readJPEG(temp)
val <- rgb( y[,,1], y[,,2], y[,,3], maxColorValue = 255)
aws.img <- matrix(val, dim(y)[1], dim(y)[2])

out = reshape2::melt(aws.img)
names(out) = c('col', 'row', 'value')
out$value = as.character(out$value)

ggplot(out) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = row, y = -col), color = out$value) + ## why do I have to flip the order of 
  theme(legend.position="none")                           ## col after reshaping?
```

Why are the colors different from the logo on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `raedJPEG` will return RGB color values on the 0/1 scale, not the 0/255 scale. Use

```
val <- rgb( y[,,1], y[,,2], y[,,3], maxColorValue = 1)
```

Also, it's usually better not to have any `$` operations in a ggplot call. Something like this would be safer

```
ggplot(out) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = row, y = -col, color = value)) +       
  theme(legend.position="none") + 
  scale_color_identity ()
```

[image]

Comment: If I replace `val <- rgb( y[,,1], y[,,2], y[,,3], maxColorValue = 255)` with `val <- rgb( y[,,1], y[,,2], y[,,3], maxColorValue = 1)` I still get those funky colors. Do I have to replace `readJPEG(temp)` with something as well?

Comment: This was test with `jpeg_0.1-8` and `R-3-5-0`. Are you using something different? The above works for me with that change.

Comment: not sure what the issue was, works perfectly now. (`R-3-4-3` and `jpeg_0.1-8`)